# what is ${modulesPath} is configuration.nix

Tags: nix, nixos

In /etc/nixos/configuration.nix, I have this code

```hs
{ lib, pkgs, config, modulesPath, ... }:
with lib;
let
  nixos-wsl = import ./nixos-wsl;
in
{
  imports = [
    "${modulesPath}/profiles/minimal.nix"

    nixos-wsl.nixosModules.wsl
  ];
```

I would like to know what "${modulesPath} is.

I have tried in shell.

```
echo ${modulesPath}
```

nothing

I have tried to print it in a nix interpreter.

```
nix repl

${modulesPath}
```

> error: syntax error, unexpected DOLLAR_CURLY
> modulePath

> error: undefined variable 'modulesPath'
> nothing too.

Does somebody what is that and more generally how to get the value of "nix constant"

**update**

I missed something important:

I have to import it in nix repl like this.

```
nix repl

{modulesPath}: modulesPath
```

> «lambda @ (string):1:1»

It say that it is a lamdba. I thought it would give a string value.

Comment: Double quotes indicate a string. Within a string, `${` and `}` delimiter a string escape, which means, everything within those symbols gets evaluated, and then converted to a string (or fail if it's not possible). In this case, this just inserts the content of the variable `modulesPath` in the string.

Comment: BTW, it's important to understand that this isn't a "nix constant" -- nix itself has no idea what `modulesPath` is; it's NixOS that defines it.

Comment: BTW, think about making a habit of using `builtins.trace` when you want to know what something is. `(builtins.trace "Loading ${modulesPath}/profiles/minimal.nix" "${modulesPath}/profiles/minimal.nix")` could go into your `configuration.nix` and would make code evaluating it write a log line telling you what the value is.

Comment: No, `{modulesPath}: modulesPath` is not telling you what `modulesPath` is, it's making a new lambda that has nothing whatsoever to do with modulesPath.

Comment: Try running `{anything}: anything`, or `{pierreHasNotLearnedNix}: pierreHasNotLearnedNix` -- both will tell you you just created a lambda as well.

Comment: Before you import nixpkgs, `nix repl` doesn't know anything about NixOS, so it _can't_ know anything about modulesPath or anything else that nixpkgs defines. And `modulesPath` isn't even at top level; it gets defined during module evaluation.

Comment: Basically, what you just did is a Nix analog of the Python expression `lambda modulesPath: modulesPath`. `modulesPath` is just the variable name used for an argument in that context; it doesn't tell you anything about what the name means in any other context.

Comment: In reading the documentation I linked you, keep in mind that `specialArgs` is used to populate the defaults that fill out arguments to modules during nixos evaluation. _If you're not evaluating a NixOS module, it won't behave the same way._

Comment: @CharlsDuffy Ok but how the configuration.nix knows what is the modulesPath?

Comment: That's described in the code comments I quote in the answer.

Comment: If you don't understand part of the answer, describe how you understand that and what parts of it are unclear, don't just pretend I never said it; ignoring things you're told is a good way to make people give up on trying to help you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will probably ask you questions latter. I think I must learn a little more about nix by myself before I do that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [the nixpkgs source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/68bd364831a89859b40d67bf94618e6163486cae/lib/modules.nix#L191-L202):

> For NixOS, `specialArgs` includes `modulesPath`, which allows you to import extra modules from the nixpkgs package tree without having to somehow make the module aware of the location of the `nixpkgs` or NixOS directories.
>
> ```
> { modulesPath, ... }: {
>    imports = [
>      (modulesPath + "/profiles/minimal.nix")
>    ];
> }
> ```

This is performed in [`nixos/lib/eval-config-minimal.nix`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/68bd364831a89859b40d67bf94618e6163486cae/nixos/lib/eval-config-minimal.nix#L42), as follows:

> ```
> lib.evalModules {
>   inherit prefix modules;
>   specialArgs = {
>     modulesPath = builtins.toString ../modules;
>   } // specialArgs;
> };
> ```

Because this is done in `<nixpkgs>/nixos/lib`, `../modules` becomes `<nixpkgs>/nixos/modules`.

```
$ nix repl
Welcome to Nix 2.8.1. Type :? for help.

nix-repl> "${toString <nixpkgs>}/nixos/modules/profiles/minimal.nix"
"/nix/store/qdblsqzrzarf9am35r6nqnvlsl7dammk-source/nixos/modules/profiles/minimal.nix"
```

...run this on your own machine, and you'll get a directory that exists for you.

Comment: I've update my question. Now in nix repl, it say that moduelsPAth is a lambda.

Comment: No, `modulesPath` is not a lambda, and `nix repl` is not telling you that it is one. When you run `{modulesPath}: modulesPath`, you just created _a brand new_ lambda that takes an attrset with the variable `modulesPath` as its argument. This tells you nothing at all about what modulesPath means in configuration.nix, where it has a meaning that has nothing to do with your lambda.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're referencing a file for a documentation-specific evaluation. The main evaluation adds it here https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/68bd364831a89859b40d67bf94618e6163486cae/nixos/lib/eval-config-minimal.nix#L42

Comment: @RobertHensing, updated appropriately, thank you.